# Access to CSS variable from component

Tags: angular, themes, angular8

I would like to know if there are any solution to access a CSS variable from a component. I am building a custom theme and I would like could change some images from a CSS template instead of adding it in the component.

For example:

I have a CSS variable:

**myComponent.scss**

```
imagePath: 'src/assets/image.jpg'
```

and I want access to that variable from the component:

**myComponent.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {
   imagePath;
}
```

**myComponent.html**

```
<img src="{{ imagePath }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the image path is defined as a CSS variable, you can access it directly from the HTML template, without having to define anything in the TypeScript component.

But there is a catch you need to know with CSS variables. They can only be used in CSS properties, not in HTML attributes like `src=...`.

You can achieve what you want by using the `background` css property:

```
<div style="background: var(--image-path);"></div>
```

Note that your declaration of the CSS variable is improper. It should start with two dashes, like that:

```
--image-path: url(...);
```

You also need to make sure the div has some width and height of course, so that you can see the background.

**DEMO**

```css
:root {
  --image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: var(--image);"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. The problem is that I also need images that cover the full page as background so that solution doesn't fits fine with my problem.

Comment: You can set dimensions of the div to fill the viewport, like `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`. Can you explain why would an `img` element fits better?